# Is there a way to get the document root on localhost in the same format that we get on remote servers (like /home/MyUserName/public_html)?

Tags: php, codeigniter, webserver, localhost, security

CodeIgniter documentations says:

> For the best security, both the ***system*** and any ***application***
>   folders should be placed above web root so that they are not directly
>   accessible via a browser.  After moving them, open your main index.php
>   file and set the $system_folder and  application_folder variables,
>   preferably with a full path, e.g. '/www/MyUser/system'.

and through echoing the PHP `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` variable I've gotten the document root of my remote server, which was `/home/MyUserName/public_html` but when I tried to do the same on my localhost I've gotten a different type of pathes (a windows path), it was `D:/xampp/htdocs`. Why? and Is there a way through which I can get a path like the first one on my localhost?

Comment: For local work why you want place these folders outside of `D:/xampp/htdocs`?

Comment: @doktorgradus Because I want to avoid changing a lot of values in the project files when moving to the remote server, I want to make the structure of the project on my localhost is almost typical to the structure of the project on the remote server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always preferable to develop/test on the target platform (Linux here), but you can have a look at something like http://cygwin.com/ if you want to stay developing on Windows. It will get you closer.

Answer (score 0):

The first path is a unix file system path - the second a windows path. It isn't necessary to have an unix style path on windows. The only thing you have to do is place codeigniter in a path, which is not accessible from outside - for example `D:/xampp/some_other_path`